# making multiple components appear in jframe with jlayeredpane

Tags: java, swing, animation, panel, thread-sleep

So I have an animation class and a garden panel class. I need the the animation jcomponent to appear on top of the garden panel jcomponent. I figured I would use jlayeredpane to help me achieve this but so far all i get is my background which i set to the color green. I figured if I added the jlayeredpane to the frame and then only added components to the jlayered pane, then I would be able to see the animation on top of the garden panel but this isn't the case so now I'm stuck. any help? Here is my class that contains the main:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
        Color c = new Color(0, 255, 0);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setBackground(c);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        Animation animation = new Animation();
        pane.add(animation);
        pane.add(new GardenPanel(6, 4, 600, 800));
        pane.setComponentZOrder(animation, 0);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while (true) {
            frame.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find a working example on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19648727/1270000

Answer (score 0):

**First:** What is your following code supposed to do?:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
while (true) {
    frame.repaint(); // repainting ?
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

using a `while(true)` loop to cycle and update your gui for every `100 ms`!!. You need to learn about Swing's single threading rule, Event Dispatching Thread and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Check this [answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19620749/java-2d-game-repaint-makes-window-grey/19625157#19625157) and reference.

**Edit: As it is advised in the comments below:**

`JLayeredPane` also incorporates with `LayoutManager` like other `JComponent`. However upon creation, it uses `AbsoluteLayout` as default by `setLayout(null)`. So Any component gets added to `layeredPane` instance should have `setBound(x, y, width, height)`. If you already have done so, then check with the `layeredPane.add(component, new Integer(index))` to control the z-index.

Comment: Then how do I add the instance of jLayeredPane to the Jframe?

Comment: I have bolded out the answer which tells you how to add. Please check

Comment: @user2510809, which guy ? what are you talking about? Look into your code. You didn't add the `JLayeredPane` instance `pane` to `JFrame` instance `frame`. You need to add it using **`frame.add(pane)`**

Comment: I'm sorry I see that now. But I Still get a view of only my background. the animation or garden panel is still not showing up. and I don't think it has to do with my while loop (i'll look into your suggestion about using event dispatch thread later). Right now I just want the animation and garden panel to both show up in my jframe.

Comment: That is something we can't answer until we see the `Animation` component and `GardenPanel` component. But one thing to mention: i think you know, `JLayeredPane` has `layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(i))` to manage the z-index. Check that If setting so works

Comment: Don't forget, `JLayeredPane`, but default, has layout manager, simply adding components to it won't do anything.  Either use an appropriate layout manager or make sure you set the size and position of the components

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes that is why I asked the OP to show the `Animation` and `GardenPanel` components code if he put `setBound`s for them. Today I was answering of an OP for fixing out his problem. I first answered his question by giving him the basic idea. Then he is contentiously saying his program is not working. Then i have spent almost 2 hours just to get fixed his code and attach the basic manipulation with his code. At the end, he didn't even say a Thank you, not even accepted the answer, stopping my mouth from being opened to other users. :(

Comment: Wait till the complain about something that has nothing to do with the original question ;)